# I cannot choose to go into Ubuntu. It boots me into windows automatically

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

I have a laptop with windows installed in 1TB hdd. I recently bought a new 256GB SSD(Gammix S5) and I installed ubuntu on it (I haven't allocated this to windows so only Ubuntu is present in it). So I have installed ubuntu only on the SSD and the installation process was successful. It asked me to restart and then remove the installation medium and I did so. Now it restarts and only boots to windows and it doesn't let me choose which OS to boot into (The grub screen doesn't show up).

Comment: In case it isn't the situation mentioned above, have you already opened UEFI settings > Boot and assured "Ubuntu" is the first priority?

Comment: Is grub and kubuntu correctly installed? Try reinstalling grub again using a usb or a CD, when you are done, it should detect all operating systems. Hopefully it'll show ubuntu, if it didn't work, try reinstalling kubuntu itself, grub will be reinstalled with it, hope this helps!